# Getting jsdoc to autocomplete

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, jsdoc

```
/**
 * @global person
 * @namespace person
 * @property {string} person.firstname
 * @property {string} person.lastname
 */
```

I have jsdoc like this.

I want it to autocomplete lastname and firstname when I type in person. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to use [`@typedef`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html):

```javascript
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Person
 * @property {string} firstname
 * @property {string} lastname
 */

// use it:
/** @type {Person} */
const Jefferey = {firstname: "Jeff", lastname: "Carver" }
```

Comment: No it's not a type, there is only ever 1 person. I want the autocomplete when I put in person dot.